# How to open a layout or view from left to right (slide open from left to right) in react native?

Tags: react-native, animation

how to move a view from left to right ( intially the view should be hidden and on first button click the view should come from left to right with animation ) partially (30%) and then on second click it should open complete .How to acheive this in react native ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand what you are asking but it sounds like a custom navigation might be possible with the library **react-navigation** . Here is a detailed blog post that shows possible customizations: https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053

Answer (score 0):

Solution lays in your approach. Having a View with screen's width doubled, render your two react components, and take a look on how to animate the hidden screen. TranslateX would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you if you learn Animated. But if you have a deadline or something, [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html) has drawer navigation. Or if you don't need navigation, there is a library called [react-native-gesture-handler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-drawer-layout.html) which has Drawer created for you.